# OAuth works in Postman but asks for more credentials in browser for callback url in vba

Tags: excel, vba

We followed the blog https://ramblings.mcpher.com/guests-articles-and-postings/oauth2-and-vba/
for generating OAuth2.0 Access Token based on Authorization Code flow of OAuth.

When we run this code

1. We are getting the sign in page, after sign in,
2. We are getting the consent page, and post that we are getting the callback url with **Authorization Code** and state **but** the callback URL is asking for more credentials on the browser.

When we used the same Oauth in Postman then it does not ask for more credentials and provides us the **Access Token**

Create a Class named "Class1" and paste the code from https://ramblings.mcpher.com/guests-articles-and-postings/oauth2-and-vba/
Create a Module file with below code and run:

```
Sub OauthClass()
Dim col1 As New Class1
Dim val1 As String
col1.InitEndPoints
col1.InitClientCredentials "<Client ID>", "<Client Secret>"
val1 = col1.AuthHeader
End Sub
```

Edit:
If I do provide the credentials again for the callback URL then I get the following error:
Authorization Failed: The callback could not be correlated with the initiating request. Please re-initiate the 'provide consent' flow.